# How to change Date format for input type="date" in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am developing android app using jquery mobile. i want to change default date format for input type = "date". how can do this?. one more thing from where the date picker is loading?
anyone help ?

eg:-

it is displaying date in following format by default: "mm/dd/yy". but i need to set this date format dynamically. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

set

```
     input_type = TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE
```

in your android.text field. this allows entering only a date.

you can parse it in your java script by doing this :

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```